# Numerical integration of modified bessel function

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I need to compute the following integral:

```
NIntegrate[ BesselI[-nu, k x]/x ,{x, r1, r}]
```

in which 
`nu=-(2m-1)/2` and I have to increase `m`, `k` is a complex number,`r1=1`, `r=1.1` as an example(`r>r1`).

When I run my code it generates errors and unreasonable answers for some values of `m`. I know that there's a closed form answer but I have to compute it numerically. How can I improve my results?

Comment: You are reposting this and I doubt you did not notice the code formatting in the thread where you originally asked this question, so please refer to the help centre and format your post accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can integrate as follows.

```
Integrate[BesselI[-nu, k*x]/x, {x, r1, r}, 
   Assumptions :> {k \[Element] Complexes, r1 \[Element] Reals, 
                   r \[Element] Reals, nu \[Element] Reals, r1 > 0, r > r1}
```

The result is a complicated expression in terms of `Gamma` and `HypergeometricPFQRegularized` functions. Nevertheless, it can be evaluated at large values of `m`. For example,

```
Block[{k=2.0536*10^(-6) + 2.3066*I, nu, r1=1.0, r=1.1, m=30},
      nu = -(2m - 1) / 2.0;
      (* long expression from NIntegrate command above *)
]

(* -4.96714*10^-31 + 4.9674*10^-31 I *)
```

Answer (score 2):

For numeric integration you need to assign numeric values for all parameters (e.g., k) and the product of k and x must include a space (k x) or an asterisk (k*x).

```
With[{k = 1 + I, r1 = 1, r = 1.1},
 Table[
  nu = -(2 m - 1)/2.;
  NIntegrate[BesselI[-nu, k x]/x, {x, r1, r}],
  {m, 6}]]
```

> {0.0691516 + 0.0652726 I, 
>    0.00791225 + 0.0454624 I, -0.00714297 + 0.0116356 I, -0.00279089 + 
>     0.000771435 I, -0.000421279 - 0.000226613 I, -0.0000195765 - 0.0000616956 I}

EDIT:

The integral can be done analytically

```
f[k_, r1_, r_, m_] = 
 Assuming[{r > r1 > 0}, Integrate[BesselI[(2 m - 1)/2, k x]/x, {x, r1, r}]]
```

[image]

For relatively large values of `m` the values of the integral are essentially zero.

```
With[{r1 = 1, r = 1.1},
  Prepend[
   Table[{m,
     f[1 + I, r1, r, m] // N,
     f[2.0536 10^-6 + 2.3066 I, r1, r, m] // N},
    {m, 30, 40, 2}],
   {"m", "k = 1 + I", "k = 2.0536*10^-6 + 2.3066I"}]] //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much but when I increase m to 30,40,... ,I can't solve the errors.

Comment: I guess it's highly oscillatory and even with LevineRule the errors don't vanish. If k is real there is no problem but when I have complex numbers...

Comment: \[Kappa] = 2.0536 10^-6 + 2.3066 I